# Iframe always needs to be loaded at the top in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, pageload

I have to make the iframe to go to the top when page loading or reloading the iframe. At the first time of page loading it is correctly loading. I scroll down the iframe and at that point. If I close the page and reopen that iframe. Always loaded from the point that I scroll down before.

But this issue comes in firefox, not in chrome. When using chrome, works properly at all the time. I have used different types of solutions by referring previous stackoverflow questions. But no one couldn't solve my issue.

1.

```
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

2. 

```
 <script>  
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }; 
 </script>
```

3. 

```
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

4. ```
    window.scroll({
       top: 0, 
       left: 0, 
       behavior: 'smooth'
     });
   ```

I tried above ways. Everyone works fine with chrome, but not in firefox. This is related to iframe.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div>
        <iframe src="" width="100%" height="750px !important" id="document-iframe"
            frameBorder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have found some jquery to reload the iframe content. Using that, only can reload the document and didn't redirect to the top of the document.

```
document.getElementById('documentIframe').src += '';
```

I have used `onload="scroll(0,0)"` also, but it is not working fine.

```
 <iframe src="" width="100%" height="750px !important" id="documentIframe"
                            frameBorder="0" onload="scroll(0,0)"></iframe>
```

Is there any special way to firefox to solve this issue. Your support is really appreciated.

Comment: Are  you saying that the user has scrolled down within the iframe or within the main page?

Comment: within the iframe